# Can not deploy helloworld app to mobilefirst development server(7.0) because of "Unable to create project lock entity" error

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-studio

Environment:
Ecipse Luna(4.4.2)
MoibleFirstStudioPlugin 7.0.0.00-20150610-1353
Mac OS X 10.10.5
java Oracle jdk1.7.0.71

I created Hello World App in moiblefirst project.
When I tried to deploy this app to development server, I got following error.

```
[2015-08-19 16:48:30]             Application 'helloworld' with all environments build finished.
[2015-08-19 16:48:30]             Deploying application 'helloworld' with all environments to MobileFirst Server... 
[2015-08-19 16:48:34]             Failed to deploy application 'helloworld' to MobileFirst Server: : HTTP 500 - Internal Server Error
```

The cause is below.

```
[ERROR   ] Unable to create project lock entity for helloworld even after 2 tries.
The project lock entity still does not exist.
```

I don't understand what these errors mean.
How can I fix it?The whole logs are below.

```
objc[1021]: Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_71.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/bin/java and /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_71.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libinstrument.dylib. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 10777
Launching worklight (WebSphere Application Server 8.5.5.4/wlp-1.0.7.cl50420141121-1414) on Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, version 1.7.0_71-b14 (en_US)
[AUDIT   ] CWWKE0001I: The server worklight has been launched.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKZ0058I: Monitoring dropins for applications. 
[WARNING ] SRVE9967W: The manifest class path xml-apis.jar can not be found in jar file wsjar:file:/Users/satohiro29894/Documents/workspace/accesstoken_touchid2/MobileFirstServerConfig/servers/worklight/apps/analytics-service.war!/WEB-INF/lib/serializer-2.7.2.jar or its parent.
[WARNING ] SRVE9967W: The manifest class path xercesImpl.jar can not be found in jar file wsjar:file:/Users/satohiro29894/Documents/workspace/accesstoken_touchid2/MobileFirstServerConfig/servers/worklight/apps/analytics-service.war!/WEB-INF/lib/xalan-2.7.2.jar or its parent.
[WARNING ] SRVE9967W: The manifest class path xml-apis.jar can not be found in jar file wsjar:file:/Users/satohiro29894/Documents/workspace/accesstoken_touchid2/MobileFirstServerConfig/servers/worklight/apps/analytics-service.war!/WEB-INF/lib/xalan-2.7.2.jar or its parent.
[WARNING ] SRVE9967W: The manifest class path serializer.jar can not be found in jar file wsjar:file:/Users/satohiro29894/Documents/workspace/accesstoken_touchid2/MobileFirstServerConfig/servers/worklight/apps/analytics-service.war!/WEB-INF/lib/xalan-2.7.2.jar or its parent.
[WARNING ] SRVE9967W: The manifest class path jaxb-api.jar can not be found in jar file wsjar:file:/Users/satohiro29894/Documents/workspace/accesstoken_touchid2/MobileFirstServerConfig/servers/worklight/apps/worklight-management-ui.war!/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-impl-2.1.12.osgi.jar or its parent.
[WARNING ] SRVE9967W: The manifest class path activation.jar can not be found in jar file wsjar:file:/Users/satohiro29894/Documents/workspace/accesstoken_touchid2/MobileFirstServerConfig/servers/worklight/apps/worklight-management-ui.war!/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-impl-2.1.12.osgi.jar or its parent.
[WARNING ] SRVE9967W: The manifest class path jsr173_1.0_api.jar can not be found in jar file wsjar:file:/Users/satohiro29894/Documents/workspace/accesstoken_touchid2/MobileFirstServerConfig/servers/worklight/apps/worklight-management-ui.war!/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-impl-2.1.12.osgi.jar or its parent.
[WARNING ] SRVE9967W: The manifest class path jaxb1-impl.jar can not be found in jar file wsjar:file:/Users/satohiro29894/Documents/workspace/accesstoken_touchid2/MobileFirstServerConfig/servers/worklight/apps/worklight-management-ui.war!/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-impl-2.1.12.osgi.jar or its parent.
[WARNING ] SRVE9967W: The manifest class path jaxb-api.jar can not be found in jar file wsjar:file:/Users/satohiro29894/Documents/workspace/accesstoken_touchid2/MobileFirstServerConfig/servers/worklight/apps/worklight-management-ui.war!/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-impl-2.1.12.osgi.jar or its parent.
[WARNING ] SRVE9967W: The manifest class path activation.jar can not be found in jar file wsjar:file:/Users/satohiro29894/Documents/workspace/accesstoken_touchid2/MobileFirstServerConfig/servers/worklight/apps/worklight-management-ui.war!/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-impl-2.1.12.osgi.jar or its parent.
[WARNING ] SRVE9967W: The manifest class path jsr173_1.0_api.jar can not be found in jar file wsjar:file:/Users/satohiro29894/Documents/workspace/accesstoken_touchid2/MobileFirstServerConfig/servers/worklight/apps/worklight-management-ui.war!/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-impl-2.1.12.osgi.jar or its parent.
[WARNING ] SRVE9967W: The manifest class path jaxb1-impl.jar can not be found in jar file wsjar:file:/Users/satohiro29894/Documents/workspace/accesstoken_touchid2/MobileFirstServerConfig/servers/worklight/apps/worklight-management-ui.war!/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-impl-2.1.12.osgi.jar or its parent.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKT0016I: Web application available (default_host): http://9.68.100.12:10080/_MobileBrowserSimulator/
[AUDIT   ] CWWKT0016I: Web application available (default_host): http://9.68.100.12:10080/analytics/
[AUDIT   ] CWWKT0016I: Web application available (default_host): http://9.68.100.12:10080/IBMJMXConnectorREST/
[AUDIT   ] CWWKT0016I: Web application available (default_host): http://9.68.100.12:10080/helloworld/
[AUDIT   ] CWWKZ0001I: Application _MobileBrowserSimulator started in 1.782 seconds.
[WARNING ] SRVE9967W: The manifest class path xml-apis.jar can not be found in jar file wsjar:file:/Users/satohiro29894/Documents/workspace/accesstoken_touchid2/MobileFirstServerConfig/servers/worklight/apps/analytics-service.war!/WEB-INF/lib/serializer-2.7.2.jar or its parent.
[WARNING ] SRVE9967W: The manifest class path xercesImpl.jar can not be found in jar file wsjar:file:/Users/satohiro29894/Documents/workspace/accesstoken_touchid2/MobileFirstServerConfig/servers/worklight/apps/analytics-service.war!/WEB-INF/lib/xalan-2.7.2.jar or its parent.
[WARNING ] SRVE9967W: The manifest class path xml-apis.jar can not be found in jar file wsjar:file:/Users/satohiro29894/Documents/workspace/accesstoken_touchid2/MobileFirstServerConfig/servers/worklight/apps/analytics-service.war!/WEB-INF/lib/xalan-2.7.2.jar or its parent.
[WARNING ] SRVE9967W: The manifest class path serializer.jar can not be found in jar file wsjar:file:/Users/satohiro29894/Documents/workspace/accesstoken_touchid2/MobileFirstServerConfig/servers/worklight/apps/analytics-service.war!/WEB-INF/lib/xalan-2.7.2.jar or its parent.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKT0016I: Web application available (default_host): http://9.68.100.12:10080/analytics-service/
[AUDIT   ] CWWKZ0001I: Application AnalyticsUI started in 10.129 seconds.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKT0016I: Web application available (default_host): http://9.68.100.12:10080/worklightconsole/
[AUDIT   ] CWWKZ0001I: Application WorklightConsole started in 12.644 seconds.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKZ0001I: Application helloworld started in 13.867 seconds.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKT0016I: Web application available (default_host): http://9.68.100.12:10080/worklightadmin/
[WARNING ] CWNEN0070W: The javax.ws.rs.CookieParam annotation class will not be recognized because it was loaded from the null location rather than from a product class loader.
[WARNING ] CWNEN0070W: The javax.ws.rs.MatrixParam annotation class will not be recognized because it was loaded from the null location rather than from a product class loader.
[WARNING ] CWNEN0070W: The javax.ws.rs.QueryParam annotation class will not be recognized because it was loaded from the null location rather than from a product class loader.
[WARNING ] CWNEN0070W: The javax.ws.rs.PathParam annotation class will not be recognized because it was loaded from the null location rather than from a product class loader.
[WARNING ] CWNEN0070W: The javax.ws.rs.HeaderParam annotation class will not be recognized because it was loaded from the null location rather than from a product class loader.
[WARNING ] CWNEN0070W: The javax.ws.rs.core.Context annotation class will not be recognized because it was loaded from the null location rather than from a product class loader.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKZ0001I: Application AnalyticsServices started in 29.995 seconds.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKF0011I: The server worklight is ready to run a smarter planet.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKZ0022W: Application WorklightServices has not started in 30.006 seconds.
[WARNING ] Using empty value for configuration property 'trusted.signer.certificate.paths'
[AUDIT   ] CWWKZ0001I: Application WorklightServices started in 33.576 seconds.
[ERROR   ] Unable to create project lock entity for helloworld even after 2 tries.
The project lock entity still does not exist.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that my workspace folder name was too long. I changed folder name from 19 characters to 7 characters. Now it works.

Comment: Can you please mark this as answered if that solved the problem.